# How to add header and footer on each page using ITextRenderer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, itext

I am stuck to the following condition where i need to generate pdf.

What i am doing is

```
String A="<html><head></head><body>Some start  html content"

String B="here the string is create **dynamic** where this can be of any length"

 String C=here its end section of html..... </body></html>"

 String finalHtml=A+B+C;
```

In my controller in using ITextRenderer in order to generate the PDF.
The content of my controller is  shown  below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/genratePdf",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPdfGenration(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){ 

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append(finalHtml);
    try{
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(buf.toString()));
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer()
        renderer.layout();
        java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
     }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

This works fine and return me pdf but the problem i am facing is to put **header** content on every page  .Any help or suggestion. I am using spring 3.1.and jar i used is iText-paulo-155.jar, itext-2.1.0.jar
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a direct access to iText's `PdfWriter`, you can use `PdfPageEvent` interface. An example of how to create headers and footers via `PdfPageEvent` can be found here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103

But if you want to add something like 'page X of Y' to your header or footer - you should use `PdfStamper` instead. An example for it can be found here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118

Comment: thanks for reply i tried second one its work but can u tell whether it accept html tag here is sample what i tried document.add(new Paragraph("<html><body><div></div>hiiii</body></html>"));. But it print the as it.

Comment: iText doesn't support HTML markup, it has it's own formatting structures. Investigate http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php, so you can find a lot of various iText examples.

Comment: I think its shouldn't  ignore html tag whether there is provision to specify that it should accept html tag also..

Comment: Ohh so sad news for me is there any way..?